# Could not pass parameters to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
function Container({sum, logMessage, doSomething}: ButtonProps,name :string) {
  console.log(sum(10, 15));

  logMessage('hello world');

  doSomething('abc');

  return <div>Hello world</div>;
}

const App = () => {
  const sum = (a: number, b: number) => {
    return a + b;
  };

  const logMessage = (message: string) => {
    console.log(message);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container sum={sum} logMessage={logMessage} doSomething={logMessage}  name = {"kasun"}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

On the above code I created two components(Container Component(Child), App Component (Parent)) and tried to pass two parameters to child component.But it gives the following error.

```
The "Property does not exist on type '{}'" error
```

Comment: Does ButtonProps have those types defined?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like maybe a typescript error related to how you're defining the props type for Container here:

`function Container({sum, logMessage, doSomething}: ButtonProps,name :string)`

I think removing the `,name :string` part will probably get rid of that error but then of course you need to make sure that ButtonProps actually defines all of the props that you're accessing.

If you were wanting to add the `name` prop you can do that like this:

```
function Container({sum, logMessage, doSomething}: ButtonProps & {name: string}) =>
```

Documentation on intersection and union types can be [found here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html).

Answer (score 1):

Props flow through a single object.

Extend `ButtonProps` with your additional props and use that compound type.

```
interface ContainerProps extends ButtonProps {
  name: string
}

function Container({sum, logMessage, doSomething, name}: ContainerProps) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Props flow through a single object.

- In the container component, you are expecting an object and a string, where the object is destructed into sum, logMessage and doSomething. so it should look like this:

---

```
type ButtonProps = {
          data: {
              sum: (a, b) => number;
              logMessage: (message) => void;
              doSomething: (message) => void;
          }
          name: string;
      };



function Container({{ sum, logMessage, doSomething }, name }: ButtonProps) {
      console.log(sum(10, 15));

      logMessage('hello world');

      doSomething('abc');

      return <div>Hello world</div>;
    }

    const App = () => {
       const sum = (a: number, b: number) => {
           return a + b;
        };

       const logMessage = (message: string) => {
           console.log(message);
        };

     return (
        <div>
           <Container data={sum, logMessage, doSomething} name = {"kasun"}/>
       </div>
     );
    };
```